# $16=m^{19} \mod 143$ - what is $m$

Tags: cryptography

The background is RSA encryption. Can I use some theorem to exploit this situation?

I thought about fermats theorem but I don t know how to use it here

fermats theorem (If a and p are coprime numbers such that $a^{p−1} − 1$ is divisible by p, then p need not be prime.)

Comment: Fermat's theorem says $a^{p-1}$ is divisible by $p$ if $p$ is prime, but $143$ isn’t prime

Comment: Hint:  solve the problem $\pmod {11}$ and $\pmod {13}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:*

We can't apply Fermat's theorem because $143 = 11 \cdot 13$ is not prime. But we can apply it to the prime factors:
$$
m^{10} \equiv 1 \bmod 11,
\quad
m^{12} \equiv 1 \bmod 13
$$
Thus, solve $19x \equiv 1 \bmod 10$ and $19x \equiv 1 \bmod 12$. Then $m = m^1 \equiv m^{19x} \equiv 16^x \bmod 143$.

Comment: I have calculated x=9 for the first equation and x = 11 for the second equation. How does this help me to calculate the last equation? Can you also tell me how you came up with this method?

Comment: @New2Math: $x$ is not $11$ for the second equation. Try again. Then solve for $x$ using your knowledge of $x\bmod 10$ and $x\bmod 12$.

Comment: Ohh can you guys please explain why $10$ and $12$ -- they are not even co-prime. Thanks.

Comment: it was x=7 - how can I proceed?

Comment: Okay I guess the solution is 19 but can  you give me an explaination for that?

Comment: how do you apply fermat to the prime factors?

Comment: how did you get that 19?

Comment: @TonyK $x=9$ for the first equation and $x=7$ for the second equation. If $x=19$ then both equations are true - do you know what $x$ is for the third equation? I really don t know but if you give me the answer I think I will understand

Comment: @New2Math: You have solved $19x\equiv 1\bmod 10$ and $19x\equiv 1\bmod 12$. So where are you stuck? Is it the calculation of $16^x\bmod 143$?

Comment: @TonyK yes - the last calculation - I don t know what the $x$ is

Comment: Yes you do. Read your previous comment carefully.

Comment: @TonyK I really don t know is it 19?

Comment: @New2Math: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a case of RSA encryption, using $n=143$ and $e=19$. As $n=13 \times 11$, $\phi(n)=2 \times 10=120$ so we need to invert $19$ modulo $120$ to find $d$.

Extended Euclid for $19$ and $120$ gives us that

$$-3 \times 120 + 19\times 19 = 1$$

so that $$d=19^{-1}\pmod{120}=19$$.

So $m=16^{19} \pmod{143}= 42$